# Scrapy. Error unexpected indent. Python

Tags: python, scrapy

Sorry for my question. 
When I run, I get an error. What am I doing wrong? Please, Help me. 
I need to get all the articles with The New York Times.

```
class OrphanSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "atical"
    allowed_domains = ["www.nytimes.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.nytimes.com/section/world?WT.nav=page&action=click&contentCollection=World&module=HPMiniNav&pgtype=Homepage&region=TopBar"]

    rules = (
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="story"]/div/',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True)
             )

             def parse_item(self, response):
                hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
                l = OrphanLoader(parse_item(), hxs)
        l.add_value('url', response.url)
        l.add_xpath('name', "//*[@id="headline"]" % u"Название статьи:")
        l.add_xpath('text', "//*[@id="story"]/div/" % u"Текст:")
```

Error:

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: `parse` method indentation is not correct. Is this the error or typo in your question?

Comment: @kuro it is error probably. What's wrong? I do not understand.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have mixed tabs and spaces in the beginning of each line.  Make them consistent, either all tabs or all spaces.  Or it could be the line: def parse_item(self, response): is not indented properly